# Expanding <UL> <LI> is working perfectly but if a link is there it is also clicking by default and then expanding which should not be the case

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul.tree li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tree li a:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding:0 .1em;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.3em;
    top: .2em;
}

ul.tree li > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '+';
}

ul.tree li.open > a:not(:last-child):before {
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
<li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript Source</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">WebReference JavaScript Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript.com</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='https://www.webdevelopment.com' target="_blank">Web Development</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='https://www.webreference.com' target="_blank">Web Reference</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.webdeveloper.com' target="_blank">Web Developer</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.wdvl.com' target="_blank">WDVL</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='https://www.forums.com' target="_blank">Forums</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='https://www.xml.com' target="_blank">XML</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.html.com' target="_blank">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.perl.com' target="_blank">Perl</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.php.com' target="_blank">PHP</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript Source</a></li>
   <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">WebReference JavaScript Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href='https://www.javascript.com' target="_blank">JavaScript.com</a></li>
 </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='https://www.web.com' target="_blank">Miscellaneous Web Sites</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='https://www.counter.com' target="_blank">The Counter</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.guestbook.com' target="_blank">The Guestbook</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.isp.com' target="_blank">The List of ISPs</a></li>
  <li><a href='https://www.jobs.com' target="_blank">Internet Jobs</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This above code is working fine in terms of expanding and collapsing. But when I am trying to expand/collapse by clicking on the word or "+" button, then it is clicking the associated link also and opening a new page which I do not want. only "+" or "-" button will do the expanding and collapsing and if I click on the word then only the link should open.

Comment: That is because you made the + a part of the anchor tag. Try making it part of the `li` tag instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I am facing some issues in doing that. Can you show me a demo?

Comment: Why do you need an `href` or `target` in the heading links? If they weren't links at all you wouldn't have a problem

Comment: Yes, Actually I need links to be associated with each and every LI UL then only my requirement will satisfy. If heading LI does not have href then there will not be any issue but I need that to be there. Thats why with this expansion/collapse I am facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the click and the icon both on the list element instead of the anchor tag. If you add it to the anchor tag, that will trigger the click on the URL.

```js
// For every list item that is expandable, toggle the open class on click
var expandableArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("expand"));

for(var index in expandableArray) {
  var list = expandableArray[index];
  list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open');
  });
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

li:not(.open) ul {
  /* Work with classes to open and close the list */
  display:none;
}

li.expand:before {
  /* Set the icon on the list tag */
  content: "+ ";
  
  /* the + icon is not an anchor tag, so set the cursor manually */
  cursor:pointer;
}

li.expand.open:before {
  content: "- ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="expand"><a href="#">test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expand"><a href="#">test</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot randy! This is the output which I want. Take a bow!
Just one query I have! Can I give just one class name at the starting <UL> , not in every expandable list and then the javascript will handle the rest the way I had posted on my question?

Comment: @SurajitMitra That would become hacky and ugly code, but it sure is possible. I don't have the time to answer that right now. Please accept this answer if it helped you and ask your question as a new question.